# which IAM Permission do I need to grant to READ running instances in region page?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am attempting to grant least permissions to an IAM User.. so they can just browse the VPC listings.. seems I've got everything I need but there's one last metric that is failing.. anyone know?

[image]

here's what I've enabled so far

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
                "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeClassicLinkInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeClientVpnEndpoints",
                "ec2:DescribeCustomerGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:DescribeEgressOnlyInternetGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeFlowLogs",
                "ec2:DescribeInternetGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeManagedPrefixLists",
                "ec2:DescribeMovingAddresses",
                "ec2:DescribeNatGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkAcls",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfacePermissions",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribePrefixLists",
                "ec2:DescribeRouteTables",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroupReferences",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroupRules",
                "ec2:DescribeStaleSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:DescribeTrafficMirrorFilters",
                "ec2:DescribeTrafficMirrorSessions",
                "ec2:DescribeTrafficMirrorTargets",
                "ec2:DescribeTransitGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeTransitGatewayVpcAttachments",
                "ec2:DescribeTransitGatewayRouteTables",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcClassicLink",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcClassicLinkDnsSupport",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpoints",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointConnectionNotifications",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointConnections",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointServiceConfigurations",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointServicePermissions",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointServices",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcPeeringConnections",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeVpnConnections",
                "ec2:DescribeVpnGateways",
                "ec2:GetManagedPrefixListAssociations",
                "ec2:GetManagedPrefixListEntries",
                "ec2:DescribeReservedInstancesListings",
                "ec2:ListSnapshotsInRecycleBin",
                "ec2:GetReservedInstancesExchangeQuote",
                "ec2:DescribeFleetInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeFleets",
                "ec2:DescribeHosts"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Example policies for working in the Amazon EC2 console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-ec2-console.html), especially the [read-only example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-ec2-console.html#ex-read-only).

The API call is [DescribeInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html).